# Entra en una condición IF cuando no debería

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente html:

```
<div class="div-trabajo">25/03/2018</div>
```

y tengo el siguiente script:

```
var f = new Date();
var diaActual = f.getDate();
var mesActual = f.getMonth();
var divTrabajo = $('.div-trabajo');
var ultimaModificacionTrabajo = $('.div-trabajo').text();
var diaTrabajo = parseInt(ultimaModificacionTrabajo.substr(-20,2));
var mesTrabajo = parseInt(ultimaModificacionTrabajo.substr(-7,2))
var fechaExpirada = diaTrabajo + 2;

if (mesTrabajo === 1 || 3 || 5 || 7 || 8 || 10 || 12 && diaTrabajo === 31){
    fechaExpirada = 2;
    console.log('entra en el primero');
}else if (mesTrabajo === 4 || 6 || 9 || 11 && diaTrabajo === 30){
    fechaExpirada = 2;
    console.log('entra en el segundo');
}
console.log(fechaExpirada);
if (fechaExpirada < diaActual){
    divTrabajo.css('color','red');
}
```

El objetivo de este script es marcar en rojo si un articulo está con fecha expirada (fecha expirada es fecha de artículo + 2 días), pero si el mes del articulo es Enero por ejemplo, y es del día 31, que no se sume 2, si no que el día pase a ser 2.

Ejecuto console log en cada condición para ver si entra en la condición.

Tal y como está el código, la fecha expirada debería de ser 27, pero por consola me devuelve 2 ¿Está mal formulada la condición?

Comment: Has mirado que `diaTrabajo` te devuelva algo? Si ninguno de los `console.log()` se ejecuta, la única forma de que `fechaExpirada `sea 2 es esa. También comentarte que en mi opinión sería mejor que `ultimaModificacionTrabajo `lo parsearas a un Date (así puedes sumar dos días y que haga el proceso de los meses automático, y te ahorras tener que meterte en rollos de años bisiestos, febrero...)

Comment: preguntas si mes trabajo es igual a 1 y luego preguntas si 3 es igual a 3 lo cual es verdadero, debes usar nuevamente la variable en cada or

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Este tipo de construccion es correcta, pero no da el resultado que te esperas:

```
if (mesTrabajo === 1 || 3 || 5 || 7 || 8 || 10 || 12 && diaTrabajo === 31)
```

Aqui estas diciendo que si mesTrabajo es igual a (operacion or entre 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10).

esto seria equivalente a comparar mesTrabajo con el resultado de todos los or, que es:

```
(1 v 3 v 5 v 7 v 8 v 10 v 12) = 15
```

por lo que siempre estas comparando, al final, mesTrabajo === 15

Probablemente tu lo que quieres es:

```
if (mesTrabajo === 1 || mesTrabajo === 3 || mesTrabajo === 5 || mesTrabajo === 7 || mesTrabajo ===8 || mesTrabajo === 10 || mesTrabajo === 12 && diaTrabajo === 31)
```

Pasa lo mismo en el else.

Comment: Muuchas gracias! es esto lo que estaba buscando. Aunque como me comenta Mikel... Creo que puede ser mas interesante que trabaje con parseDate.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo. Es mejor que hagsa el parse y operes directamente con fechas en lugar de cortar y esas cosas... mas que nada porque puedes tener problemas a la hora de trabajar con grupos de trabajos que empiezan en un mes y terminan en otro, y cosas por el estilo.

Comment: de igual manera, es importante saber bien la forma de operar con las condiciones. Muchas gracias Jakala